# If I have two diagonalisable matrices A and B. How can I write matrix A in the eigenvalues basis of matrix B?

Tags: matrices

I got this doubt while reading matrix representation of operators in Quantum Mechanics. And it left me wondering whether we can represent any general diagonalizable matrix in the eigenvalue basis of another matrix. If so can you please suggest me any material to study about this method

Comment: Sorry, can you be a little more specific about what you're confused about? You can always represent any operator by a matrix in any basis.

Comment: This question doesn't make sense as stated.

Comment: Yes, that exactly is my doubt. I don't know how to represent any matrix in an arbitary basis. I just want to know the method by which we can perform the above operation

Comment: Have you tried searching the Web for “change of basis?”

Comment: Thanks I just did